# how to check Goodness of fit for Gamma Distribution, Weibull Distribution, Exponential Distribution with Anderson Darling Test

Tags: exponential, weibull, gamma-distribution

> how to check Goodness of fit for Gamma Distribution, Weibull
> Distribution, Exponential Distribution with Anderson Darling Test?
> Thankyou

Comment: have you already Googled

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.